# Printing output in a loop and printing a newline

Tags: java

I have written a simple program in java to find the factorial, which works fine. I am now trying to refine the output, but I'm not sure how to do it.

My Program:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class UserInput {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int fact = 1;

        Scanner number = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter the number : ");
        int n = number.nextInt();
        if (n < 0) {
            System.out.println("Enter positive number");
        } else {
            System.out.print("Factorial Sequence is :");
            for (int i = n; i >= 1; i--) {
                fact = fact * i;
                System.out.print(i + "*");
            }

            System.out.println("Factorial of number " + n + " is :" + fact);
        }

    }
}
```

Output shown is in this format (a single line, * after the 1):

> Factorial Sequence is :5*4*3*2*1*Factorial of number 5 is :120

I want output in this format:

> Factorial Sequence is :5*4*3*2*1
>   Factorial of number 5 is :120

Comment: add println instead of print

Comment: Add a "\n" to the beginning of your last `System.out.println` to add in the new line at least.

Comment: You should accept one of the answers to show that the question has been answered and there is a good solution. Choose the best answer in your opinion by clicking the checkmark to the left of the answer.

Answer (score 3):

Since 1 is not going to modify the factorial result your code can be rewriten as:

```
        for (int i = n; i >= 2; i--) {
            fact = fact * i;
            System.out.print(i + "*");
        }
        System.out.println("1");
```

Comment: This very cleverly avoids a conditional within the for loop - added a note to my answer to see your answer ;)

Comment: @Brian Try it if you don't believe it :) It adds a new line after 1 is printed!

Comment: Oh right, println adds the newline at the end, but the print before it has no newline... heh.

Answer (score 1):

To make the gap, you can add an `\n` literal to represent a newline.

```
 System.out.println("\nFactorial of number " + n + " is :" + fact);
```

And for the last `*`, you can either remove it at the end or not add it if `i` is 1..

```
 System.out.print(i + (i > 1?"*":""));
```

This says if `i` is greater than `1`, return a `*`, otherwise return an empty string.

Comment: First sop statement is works fine but if i m using the sop statement with ternary operator it's not giving me desired result. Could you please elaborate it. Because i like this approach. i am using this way : for (int i = n; i >= 1; i--) {
    fact = fact * i;
    System.out.print(i); 
    System.out.print(i+i > 1 ? "*" : "");

Comment: I've added some brackets. That might sort it. Have a look at my edit. I would, however, strongly recommend that you look at @demostene answer. His is the optimal solution up until now.

Comment: It worked... nice solution and learned the practical use of ternary operator. I agree demostene solution is also one of profound solution

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to use string concatenation during your for loop:

```
String s = "Factorial Sequence is :";
for (int i = n; i >= 1; i--) {
    fact = fact * i;
    s += i + (i > 1 ? "*" : "");
}
System.out.println(s);
```

Only 'benefit' this has over the other options is it saves calling System.out.print each iteration, at the expense of a string concatenation operation. Probably no performance difference at all, and certainly not significant here, but it is an alternate means to the same end.

EDIT: Use @demostene's excellent suggestion to avoid the final '*' after the final '1' - it avoids the conditional expression within the for loop, which is really nice as your factorial becomes larger.

Comment: A link with no explanation of why you are linking it is not helpful. What would be the point of using StringBuilder over standard concatenation?

Comment: The concatenation creates new String instances (if not already interned) for every result.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, Tom, that is indeed helpful.

Comment: But you should know that the compiler *might* replace the concatenation with `StringBuilder` calls anyway in order to improve that code.

Comment: Depends on the compiler, though I seriously doubt using StringBuilder (which would be taking new Strings as an argument in #append) vs. two new strings per iteration has any impact on performance. See cost of new objects question: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/149563/should-we-avoid-object-creation-in-java

Comment: Let's take your code as an example: #append wouldn't get new Strings in every iteration: only `"*"` or `""` and these String were created once. But if you use concatenation, then `"5*"` would be a new String, then `"5*4*"` another new String and `"5*4*3*"` and so on. This might have no great impact in this little code snippet, but if you use String concatenation in a bigger project, then it has. So it is a good idea to get familiar with `StringBuilder` instead.

Comment: Wouldn't each int also be converted to a new char/string when appended? Anyway, I agree that if you are doing massive amounts of string manipulations, StringBuilder is a good choice.

Comment: No, because there are separate [#append methods for primitive types](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html#append%28int%29). They don't need to be converted to String.

Comment: The implementations of which surely must convert the primitive type to a string or char in order to add it to the current string: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html#append(int)

Comment: It doesn't seems so for the int version: http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/lang/AbstractStringBuilder.java#AbstractStringBuilder.append%28int%29. (except for the Integer.MIN_VALUE situation)

Comment: That's a neat website xD However, the documentation of the method itself even specifies: "The argument is converted to a string as if by the method String.valueOf, and the characters of that string are then appended to this sequence."

Comment: I guess the most important part is `The overall effect` (you've missed that part :P). It doesn't necessarily mean that `String.valueOf` will be called. It just has the same *effect*, but "they" can also use byte shift and conversion to `char` to get each separate number of the passed integer. This happens in my provided code/link in *openJDK* of version 6. It might be different on newer version or in other JDKs. But it is an interesting topic.

Comment: And what do you expect String.valueOf does when it encounters an int? Likely identical or very similar implementation with a negligible performance difference. Anyway, we should end this discussion as it is no longer contributing to the question.

Comment: Well it doesn't matter what it does, because at the end it creates a String instance, but in StringBuilder the letters/numbers will be added to the char array (which StringBuilder seems to hold). And yes, we can end this here. But it was nice.

Answer (score 0):

Just add a print line statement:

```
System.out.println(); // add this line
System.out.println("Factorial of number " + n + " is :" + fact);
```

Comment: Also he wants there to not be a `*` after the last number.

Comment: Start the for loop counter with a 2 then print 1 at the end.

Comment: No problem. And you can always click the edit button underneath your answer to update your answer. You should do that with the information you just commented and add the code for it.